# ImportError at /admin/ No module named polls_ChoiceField.urls

Tags: django, python-2.7

Django 1.6.2
MacOSX 10.9.2
Python 2.7

I recently deleted a Django App "polls_ChoiceField" which was sitting inside another app "polls" as I was only using it to test a few things. However since i deleted it then the app it was sitting in no longer works.

I deleted the file through the pyDev package explorer. When I synced the Database it gave my the option of deleting the stale content, I selected yes.

Can anyone tell me what I have to do to get the original "polls" all running again?

**Relevant Terminal output**

```
localhost:src brendan$ python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

    polls | choice_choicefield
    polls | poll_choicefield

Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.

    Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

I then synced the DB

```
localhost:src brendan$ python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

And I am able to run the server

```
localhost:src brendan$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
```

**When i try to revisit the app in my browser i get**

```
ImportError at /polls/

No module named polls_ChoiceField.urls

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls/
Django Version:     1.6.2
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named polls_ChoiceField.urls

Exception Location:     /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 40
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/Users/brendan/Dropbox/workspace/bias_experiment/src',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.7.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/yolk-0.4.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-4.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 28 Apr 2014 16:26:46 +0100
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**
My urls.py with the bad line of code  (the middle url)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^polls_ChoiceField/', include('polls_ChoiceField.urls', namespace="polls_ChoiceField")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Show your `urls.py` and `INSTALLED_APPS` settings.

Comment: Sorted! That was it exactly. I have a top level urls.py directing into each of the sub apps which was still referencing the old app.
If you add this as an answer i will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your project-level `urls.py`, looks like it still tries to use `urls` from the deleted app.